# Using session timeout through jQuery and handler

Tags: jquery, handler

I am using this code for managing timeout from jQuery and handler. Everything is working fine but not able to call handler and response not coming.

```
function SessionTimeoutModel(root) {
var self = this;
this.counter = ko.observable();

this.startSessionTimeOut = function () {
    jQuery.idleTimeout('#timeout-content', '#timeout-continue-session', {
        idleAfter: 50,
        pollingInterval: 270,
        failedRequests: 100,
        keepAliveURL: "/svc/SessionKeepAlive.ashx",
        serverResponseEquals: "Ok",
        onTimeout: function () {
            if (!pageStats.statsSaved) {
                pageStats.statsUpdate();
            }
            window.location = "/logon?session=TIMEOUT";
        },
        onIdle: function () {
            jQuery('#session-expire-message').overlay({ mask: '#000000', closeOnClick: false });
            jQuery('#session-expire-message').overlay().load();
        },
        onCountdown: function (counter) {
            self.counter(counter) // update the counter
        }
    });

    var overlayObj = jQuery("#session-expire-message").data("overlay");
    if (overlayObj) overlayObj.close();
}
```

I need to call "keepAliveURL: "/svc/SessionKeepAlive.ashx" then according to response it can work.

Comment: I am not sure a specific problem is described here, containing sufficient detail to enable readers to help you. Have you done any debugging? Is the outer function called so the `jQuery.idleTimeout` line is called? If that is run, which of the handlers are you expecting to run (`onTimeout`, `onIdle`, `onCountdown`)?

Comment: Yes i did debugging, and yes outer function is calling. 
i need to call "keepAliveURL: "/svc/SessionKeepAlive.ashx" then according to response it can work.

also can you please provide any JS code which can help me for stopping timeout

Comment: OK. I assume your code above is what you have tried, and it does not work. Have you looked at your network tab in your browser, to see if the requests are not being made, or there are JS errors, or the server is not handling the request correctly?

Comment: yes i have checked on network tab no any js errors are there

Comment: Are there any HTTP requests and responses being made by this code?

Comment: yes http response is there

Comment: Perhaps it would help to show your request and response data in the question. Would you edit it to make that change? I am not sure there is enough information to help at the moment.

Comment: yes http response is there – and that is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please edit your question to explain what that means exactly.

Comment: basically when i have tried to add code like when we not in system and logged in to website then it shows popup for timeout when you will click on "Continue" then session will continue working and if did not perform any operation then it will expire session

Comment: As above, **Perhaps it would help to show your request and response data in the question**. Please edit your question.